# Eclipse Plug-in : submenu in menuContribution

Tags: java, xml, menu, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to understand more submenus in a menuContribution, here's what I've done so far :

```
MenuManager submenu = new MenuManager("Commands", "com.org.new.commands");
CommandContributionItemParameter p = new CommandContributionItemParameter(
            serviceLocator, "",
            "org.eclipse.ui.file.exit",
            SWT.PUSH);
p.label = "Exit the application";
p.icon = Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/alt_window_16.gif");

CommandContributionItem item = new CommandContributionItem(p);
item.setVisible(true);
submenu.add(item);
additions.addContributionItem(submenu, null);
```

So normally with this code I create a menu which contains the "Exit the application" command. But instead of that, my "Commands" menu is simply not available.

Here's my XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension-point id="iCommand" name="ICommand" schema="schema/iCommand.exsd"/>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
      class="model.ExtensionLoader"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">

  </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

I don't exactly understand everything about the menuManager yet, so if someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong, that would be wonderful !

Comment: It is unusual to use the `class` attribute of `menuContribution`, I don't see anything in the core Eclipse that uses it. Most of the time you can do everything with the `command` and `menu` elements.

Comment: Actually the goal of the exercice here is to implement our very own command extension plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.eclipse.ui.menus extension to add a command inside an existing menu. Also to make that command available you have to create it using org.eclipse.ui.commands and org.eclipse.ui.handlers .

You can refer to this link:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html

in order to understand better how these extensions work